# Nativescript with vue and ts fail to build

Tags: nativescript

I created a nativescript vue template:

```
 sudo vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template project
```

When I try to run it with the command: `tns run`, I get the following errors:

```
Gradle build...

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/home/petar/Documents/Workspace/js/project/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 221

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Invalid revision: undefined

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/petar/Documents/Workspace/js/roomy/roomy/platforms/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Unable to apply changes on device: 2383f95c9f0d7ece. Error is: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1.
```

Also, I get a couple of warnings just after I run the command. I installed Android studio, tried to set the JAVA_HOME variable correctly, and a couple of other things, but nothing worked.

```
✖ The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android. 
 To be able to perform Android build-related operations, set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable to point to the root of your Android SDK installation directory. 

✖ WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.  
 For Android-related operations, the NativeScript CLI will use a built-in version of adb.
To avoid possible issues with the native Android emulator, Genymotion or connected
Android devices, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK and
its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements 

✖ WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly. 
 You will not be able to run your apps in the native emulator. To be able to run apps
in the native Android emulator, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK 
and its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements
```

Comment: Can you post entire error log, the error you have posted is very generic and minimal.

Comment: Yes, of course, one second

Comment: Okay, I added the full error message :)

Comment: Is that you are not able to run the CLI template with class component Or you are unable to run at all? Are you sure you have configured Android SDK already, with all required API levels, platform tools etc?

Comment: I am unable to run at all. But I am not sure if I have correctly configured all the stuff you said, more likely no. What exactly should I configure?

Comment: You are on Mac or Windows? I think it's better you run through the setup guide for respective platform.

Comment: I am using Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

You have installed Android Studio but possibly haven't, as error 2 and tns points to, set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable.
What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu.